# Regex to parse URL from an excel formula

Tags: c#, regex, excel

I have a formula in excel which upon reading from C# code looks like this

```
"=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(\"https://abc.efghi.rtyui.com/#/wqeqwq/\",#REF!,\"/asdasd\"), \"View asdas\")"
```

I want to use regex to fetch the URL from this string, i.e.

*https://abc.efghi.rtyui.com/#/wqeqwq/#REF!/asdasd*

The url can be different but the format of the formula will remain the same.

```
"=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(\"{SOME_STRING}\",#REF!,\"{SOME_STRING}\"), \"View asdas\")"
```

Comment: I think you wish to parse the URL value AFTER the concatenation was done. Now, this is trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
(?<=HYPERLINK\(CONCATENATE\(")[^"]+
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/2FyFrL/1/)

The [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) allows us to skip part in-front of the URL from the full match.
If you have an arbitrary number of whitespace in-between add some `\s*`, e.g. see [this example](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5C%3D%5Cs*HYPERLINK%5Cs*%5C%28%5Cs*CONCATENATE%5Cs*%5C%28%5Cs*%22%29%5B%5E%22%5D%2B&i=%3DHYPERLINK%28CONCATENATE%28%22https%3A%2F%2Fabc.efghi.rtyui.com%2F%23%2Fwqeqwq%2F%22%2C%23REF!%2C%22%2Fasdasd%22%29%2C%20%22View%20asdas%22%29) that also shows the escaped `=` at the beginning of the string.

Sample Code:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(?<=HYPERLINK\(CONCATENATE\("")[^""]+";
        string input = @"=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(""https://abc.efghi.rtyui.com/#/wqeqwq/"",#REF!,""/asdasd""), ""View asdas"")";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Addendum: Here is another technique that uses capturing groups and regex Replace to extract the resulting URL string (after CONCATENATE would have happened):

```
^\=HYPERLINK\(CONCATENATE\("([^"]+)",([^,]+),"([^"]+)".*$
```

[**Demo2**](https://regex101.com/r/4CBPnr/1)

```
string pattern = @"^\=HYPERLINK\(CONCATENATE\(""([^""]+)"",([^,]+),""([^""]+)"".*$";
string substitution = @"$1$2$3";
string input = @"=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(""https://abc.efghi.rtyui.com/#/wqeqwq/"",#REF!,""/asdasd""), ""View asdas"")";

    Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
    string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the URL from the formula using capturing groups in regular expression as given below:

```
string inputString = "=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(\"https://abc.efghi.rtyui.com/#/wqeqwq/\",#REF!,\"/asdasd\"), \"View asdas\")";
string regex = "CONCATENATE\\(\"([\\S]+)\",#REF!,\"([\\S]+)\"\\)";
Regex substringRegex = new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match substringMatch = substringRegex.Match(inputString);
if (substringMatch.Success)
{
    string url = substringMatch.Groups[1].Value + "#REF!" + substringMatch.Groups[2].Value;
}
```

I have defined two capturing groups in my regular expression. One for extracting part of the URL before #REF! and the other for extracting part of the URL after #REF!. Then I am concatenating all the extracted parts with #REF! to get the final URL.